# I want to move 'app' dir to 'app/back', it's possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In order to add 'app/front' (JS code will be here) I want to move 'app' dir to 'app/back', it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to have separate folders for 'backend' / 'front-end' styles and javascripts?  If so, you can arrange your folder structures like so:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/front-end/
app/assets/javascripts/front-end/
app/assets/stylesheets/back-end/
app/assets/javascripts/back-end/
```

Then I'd make a separate layout, `admin_layout.html.erb` that references your `back-end` stylesheets and javascripts.  Make sure to add `config.assets.precompile += ['backend.css', backend.js']` to your `application.rb` so they're compiled (assuming you removed `require_tree .` from your application.css/js file.

Comment: I have A LOT JS code (about 1:1), and very frustrated about long paths (like 'app/assets/javascripts/app'. So its solution is not suitable, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I understand your question then.